# Linearization of a min function

Tags: optimization, non-convex-optimization

I'm trying to solve an optimization problem with a constraint in the form of

$\alpha + \sum^K_{k=1}\frac{x[k]}{\min(f_1(x[k]),\cdots,f_{n_k}(x[k]))} \le \epsilon$, where $x[k] > 0,\, \forall k$ are the optimization variables

My question: Is it correct to assume that this constraint is equivalant to :

$\alpha + \sum^K_{k=1} x[k]\max_{{j}_{k}}\{\frac{1}{f_{{j}_{k}}(x[k
])}\} \le \epsilon \longleftrightarrow \alpha + \sum^K_{k=1} \frac{x[k]}{f_{{j}_{k}}(x[k
])} \le \epsilon\quad \forall k,{{j}_{k}} $

where the functions $f_{j_k}(x[k])=\log(1+\beta_{j_k}x[k]),\, \forall j_k,k$ are concave and are always positive for $x[k]>0$, and $\alpha,\epsilon, \beta> 0$

Thanks

Comment: More details are needed such as the sign of $x[k]$ and the functions $f_i$. Assuming those are positive then, you can substitute the max term by $t[k]$ and add the constraint $1/f_j(x[k])\le t[k]$ for all $i=1,\ldots,n$ and $k=1,\ldots,K$.

Comment: Edited thanks, they're indeed positive. I assume $t[k]$ shall be also optimized too ?

Comment: Yes, those are also decision variables. The equivalence you gave is also true in this case as $x[k]$ is positive.

Comment: I see, however then this constraint will no more be convex in those two variables, i.e due to the product $x[k]\times t[k]$, am I right?

Comment: Not in general. There is also a small typo in your equivalence. It should be $f_{j_k}(x[k])$ for all $j_k$.

Comment: Edited again, many thanks for your response, it's more clear now. I'll edit the post to mention that $f(x) = \log(1+x)$ too.